# Cannot use initialised local variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use a local variable in a TensorFlow model and I am finding trouble to do so. I have summarised my problem to the following example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    v = tf.get_local_variable('myvar', [1, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.variables_initializer([v])]):
        v2 = tf.identity(v, name='myvar2')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(v2))
```

I would expect to get `[[ 0. ]]`, but instead I get the error:

```
FailedPreconditionError (see above for traceback): Attempting to use uninitialized value myvar
         [[Node: myvar/read = Identity[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@myvar"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](myvar)]]
```

How am I supposed to initialise and use a local variable then?

I am using TensorFlow 1.0.0 and Python 3.5.

*UPDATE:*

I have noted that doing the initialisation assignment myself *does* work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    v = tf.get_local_variable('myvar', [1, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    v_assigned = v.assign(tf.zeros(v.get_shape(), v.dtype))
    v2 = tf.identity(v_assigned, name='myvar2')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(v2))
```

So are then initialisers **always** run at the end of the session, no matter how you set your dependencies? Or is there something else I am missing?

Note: This solution is not enough for me (as it is, at least) because I want to do sliced assignments in my variables, and I cannot do that on the returned value of `.assign`, which is a reference to the variable, not the variable itself. I have seen that using `v_assigned` as control dependency and then assigning to `v` seems to work, but I don't know if that's reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the problem is that I was assuming that using `tf.identity` would give me a reference to the variable but updated with the current control dependencies, but that is not the case; it just gives me a reference to the old (possibly uninitialised) value. So the right way to go about it is to use the `read_value` method of `tf.Variable`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40901870/1782792). So the correct code would be:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    v = tf.get_local_variable('myvar', [1, 1], initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())
    with tf.control_dependencies([tf.variables_initializer([v])]):
        v2 = tf.identity(v.read_value(), name='myvar2')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(v2))
```